# Angular - Reactive form not updating after form.setValue()

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In my project I have a structure with custom html elements, similar to the following:

- AppComponent

  - CustomElement1

    - CustomElement2

Basically the `CustomElement2` is child of `CustomElement1`, which is child of `AppComponent`. It's the first time I using custom elements with more than 1-level-deep, which is giving me some problems.

The following code gives the idea:

custom-element-2.html:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input readonly matInput placeholder="ID" formControlName="id" >
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input readonly matInput placeholder="Type" formControlName="type" >
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input readonly matInput placeholder="Price" copyable formControlName="price" >
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

custom-element-2.ts

```
constructor() {
  this.form = fb.group({
    'id': [],
    'type': [],
    'price': [],
  })

  httpCall()
   .subscribe(json => {
     const product = json.data[0] //data is returning perfectly.

     this.form.setValue({
      'id': product.id,
      'type': product.type,
      'price': product.price
     })
}
```

In CustomElement2 there is a form that starts with empty value, waiting for an api response. When the response returns, I call `form.setValue()` with the correct form controls, but the view does not update. I always use this approach in every form implementation and I never had this problem, so I imagine it might be related to the custom elements structure as it's the first time I'm using it.

How could I make the view re-render after the form value update?